# Website hack resulting in auto redirect - where to start looking?

Tags: php, apache, security, hacking

My website is being redirected to a non-existent page (`/showpage.php`) for some users when they hit the homepage.  For other users, the site works fine. I have looked in the `index.php` files and some other commonly used files.  I believe strongly that this is a hack but I don't know how to get rid of it.

Any advice on where to start looking? Any experience dealing with something like this? I would greatly appreciate even the slightest thought on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

Check your htaccess file as that is commonly where redirect hacks are placed. If you can't find it anywhere ask your host to check the Apache conf files as they may be the ones who are comprimised.

Answer (score 2):

Searching on the associated filename in online exploit databases can sometimes yield insights/hints. For example, [this](http://www.toexploit.com/exploit/php/quality-point-10-newsfeed-sqlxss-multiple-remote-vulnerabilities) exploit can affect the noted PHP webapp script (*Warning: do not click on the demo there for the XSS exploit*).

As indicated in that, this involves two types of common exploits:

- [Cross-site scripting (XSS) exploits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) - used to bypass access controls in browsers.
- [SQL injection exploits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - used to attack data-driven applications.

There are many virus and web security scanner applications that utilize exploit databases, which can run on and monitor your server. An outdated list of some of them can be found [here](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246988/Web%20Application%20Security%20Scanner%20List) - search for others in Google.